# When do you need to manually reload a lightning data service record?

Tags: lightning-data-service

I use lightning data service (lds) multiple times in different parts of my app. Each use of lds involves the same record. Do I need to manually reload it each time a change event is detected? So say in part A of my app, the record is updated, do I need to do a`component.find('recordEditor').reloadRecord()` in the change event for part B, C, D, etc that lds is used? Or does lds take care of that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it out myself, but based on the below excerpt from [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_data_service/lightning_data_service_handle_notifications), it doesn't seem that you need to force reload every time with the change (emphasis mine).

> When LDS detects a record change, it notifies the components that use the record of the changes. **If you don’t handle the change, the record is still updated**, so any reference to the `targetRecord` or `targetFields` properties automatically shows up in your components. For every `force:recordData` component referencing the updated record, LDS does two things.
>
> - LDS notifies all other instances of `force:recordData` of the change by firing the recordUpdated event with the appropriate `changeType` and `changedFields` value.
> - It sets the `targetRecord` and `targetFields` attribute on each `force:recordData` to the new record value. If `targetRecord` or `targetFields` is referenced by any UI, this automatically triggers a rerender so that the UI displays the latest data.

Later it also mentions about **Edit** mode scenarios where the records are not updated automatically, which seems reasonable.

> If `force:recordData` is in EDIT mode, `targetRecord` and `targetFields` are not automatically updated when the record changes. This is to avoid clobberin’ edits that are still in progress and to prevent unsaved changes from appearing in other components. Never fear, records can be refreshed manually by handling the `recordUpdated` event and calling the `reloadRecord` method.

Comment: I have the similar issue but I am not using the using the force:recordData but instead the recordEditForm https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321652/refresh-the-page-from-the-lightning-component can you please help what I am missing here

Answer (score 1):

I would say the right time to reload LDS is on the callback method of any Apex calls that modified the record, or any other time you are somehow aware the record changed without the knowledge of the Lightning framework on the current page. A nice advantage of doing this is, it also refreshes the Details view on the record page. As a result, even in components that don't otherwise use LDS, I will include `force:recordData` and use it to refresh Details fields after Apex is finished with a change.

Comment: Will calling `recordReload` in the callback record reload every instance that I'm using LDS, or just in the component that it is being used?

Comment: Every LDS instance of the same record in that browser tab. However I think it only reloads the fields specified even if other instances have other fields they're using.

Comment: Have you ever reloaded LDS after an apex call that modifies the record? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It's worked for me in the past year but I have not re-tested recently.