# Refresh the page from the Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-data-service

I am having the Lightning component that uses the Lightning Data Services to update the fields on the Case record, it works fine if the component is updating fields like status or origin like that. But when I try to update the record type/owner the page is  not refreshed after the update happens.

Below is the component where I am updating the record type and Owner basically it is like transfering the case from one Dept to another

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global"  >
<aura:attribute name="loaded" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<lightning:spinner variant="brand" alternativeText="Loading..." class="{!(v.loaded? 'slds-show': 'slds-hide')}" />
 <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form" 
        objectApiName="Case" 
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
        onerror="{!c.handleError}"
        onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="statusInput" fieldName="Status" class="slds-hide" />
        <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" label="SF Support" />
 </lightning:recordEditForm>    
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.loaded',true);
        event.preventDefault();      
        var fields = event.getParam('fields');
        
        fields.OwnerId = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; // Owner is SF Support           
        fields.RecordTypeId = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYY';
        fields.Status = 'New';
        console.log(JSON.stringify(fields)); 
        component.find('form').submit(fields);
        
    },
    
    handleError: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.loaded',false);
        const fieldErrors = event.getParam('output').fieldErrors;
        const separator = ' ';
        
        let errMessage = Object.values(fieldErrors).map(field => {
            return field.map(error => error.message).join(separator);
        }).join(separator);
        
        $A.get("e.force:showToast")
        .setParams({
            type: 'error',
            mode: 'pester',
            message: errMessage  }).fire();       
    },
    
    handleSuccess: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.loaded',false);
        $A.get("e.force:showToast")
        .setParams({
            type: 'success',
            message: 'Case passed to Salesforce Support!',
            mode: 'pester'
        })
        .fire();
    }
})
```

Though the Owner/RecordType is updated the page is not refreshed. Below screesnshot shows the page is not refreshed , I should be seeing the Owner as SF Support but it still shows the old owner Services  but Toast is fired saying the case is passed.

[image]

But when do the full page refresh it shows up SF Support. Can anyone please help me what I am missing here

Comment: The code does refresh the owner value for me. The detail component is the standard component or you have custom detail component?

Comment: It is the standard component, when the button is clicked it freezes the screen for sometime and doesnt let me refresh the browser

Comment: @sanketkumar Did you change the record type as well when you tried ?

Comment: yes, i have tried both and worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you think any reason for this behavior I am seeing. Is it safe to use the .reload() with the controller on the handlesuccess?

Comment: I suggest you to keep your lightning page pretty simple and remove custom component and then try it. In my case, there was no other custom component than this.

Comment: I suggest you to keep your lightning page pretty simple and remove custom component and then try it. In my case, there was no other custom component than this.

Comment: @sanketkumar I do have multiple components on the page which cannot be removed, but can I use the reload() method to do a full page refresh on the handleSuccess do you see any issues using it